# colour="black" in geom_smooth changes lm line with R gglplot2. Why?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My examples are made with easy available data:

```
data(Salaries, package="car")
library(tidyverse)
```

When running:

```
ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, color=rank))+
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method="lm", size=0.5)+
facet_grid(~sex)
```

I got this graph which creates an lm line for every rank:

[image]

But when I use

```
ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, color=rank))+
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method="lm", colour="black", size=0.5)+
facet_grid(~sex)
```

The graph shows now an unique lm line for all data:

[image]

Any idea of what's happening? Why setting colour="black" changes the whole appearence of the lm line in the graphic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because by specifying `color` in `geom_smooth`, you are overriding the aesthetics set in the top line of your code. If you want the lines for all groups to be black, you can use the `group`-aesthetic in `geom_smooth` the following way:

```
ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, color=rank))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(group=rank), method="lm", color = "black", size=0.5)+
  facet_grid(~sex)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The aesthetics are re-used in every layer: from `help(aes)`

*Aesthetics supplied to ggplot() are used as defaults for every layer. 
You can override them, or supply different aesthetics for each layer*

When you define *colour* as the levels of rank, ggplot does just that. At the moment you **override the colour setting** (levels of rank) in the call to `geom_smooth`, ggplot drops the levels for plotting the line.

you could work around this by using `fill` and `shape=21` and using `color` for the line like this:

```
ggplot(Salaries, aes(x=yrs.since.phd, y=salary, fill=rank))+
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", 
              color="black",
              size=0.5)+
  facet_grid(~sex)
```

adding `se=FALSE` to the call to `geom_smooth` will drop the coloured standard error intervals.

yielding this plot:

[image]